# In UITableViewCell, how can I change the style of the clicked button bold, while the other cells remain still?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

The only thing UITableViewCell contains is one UIButton. So far, I can print the 'currentTitle' of the clicked UIButton on console. What I'd like to do is change the style of the clicked button bold. If another one is clicked, the former one should go back to regular and the new one needs to change bold.

It they were multiple buttons in a UIViewController, I would have easily done this by adding those buttons separately but I don't think this case will be done in that way.

Should I save the index of the selected button in the UIViewController class, and reload the UITableView? If so, can anyone let me know how to handle this? I have this idea but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var selectIndex:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("ButtonAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)

    if indexPath.row == selectIndex.row
    {
        cell.btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
    }
    return cell
}

func ButtonAction(sender: UIButton) 
{
    selectIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

CustomTableViewCell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^ButtonTapAction)(CustomTableViewCell *aCell);
```

CustomTableViewCell.m

```
//Method assign to that button
- (IBAction)arrowButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.ButtonTapAction) {
        self.ButtonTapAction(self);
    }
}
```

cell Used in tableview cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        cell.arrowButtonTapAction = ^(CustomTableViewCell *aCell){
            aCell.button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        };
```

By Using this code you dont need to reload Cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property that stores the row that corresponds to the cell with the currently selected button.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you check whether `indexPath.row == selectedRow` and set the button appearance appropriately.

When the selection changes, call `reloadCellsAtIndexPaths` with the newly selected row and the previously selected row if applicable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` keep a flag saying it has been selected.

Also you have to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on `tableView.visibleCells` for  when the button is selected, because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only works when the cell is coming into view.

Comment: You shouldn't call the table view datasource methods directly

Comment: @Paulw11 then whats the solution for the above problem?

Comment: Have it called implicitly by asking the table view to reload the affected cells with `reloadCellsAtIndexPaths` or `reloadData`